# I want to remove a load bearing wall, which support is best beam or deadman?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, structural, beam, support

I have a Block foundation. I want to extend my living room by removing a 12' section of load bearing wall. Dimensions 12'x2x6 junction to 5'x2x6 ceiling span

Would I need to reinforce the foundation at the ends? And
If I use a 2x12 centered over the junction of the 12'x2x6 and the 5'2x6 How many and how long would screws need to be? And what would the dimensions of a two ply OSB laminate need to be?

Comment: You really should have a structural engineer to design the work.  Any mistakes made could have very bad outcomes.  Removing load bearing walls usually will require permits, which require engineer drawings.

Comment: Ditto crip659, this isn't info you want to coble together from the internet.  You need an engineer to design it.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the answer you want, but:

It is impossible for anyone to say without a blueprint of your house, and a structural engineering degree.

Google "structural engineers near me" setup an appointment, tell them what you want to do (extend living room, add a beam to remove a load bearing wall). They will tell you what to bring (blueprint, most likely + your plans)/how much the consultation will cost.

Then you will need to get a permit and hire some professionals to do it for you. The second you start messing with load bearing walls, you want someone else to do it for you. You don't want things to go wrong (roof collapses, etc..). And if things go wrong, you will want a bonded licensed professional with insurance that will cover the damage.

Don't try save money on this, it will cost you a lot more... New houses are expensive.